# Converting an existing Nodejs Express application to a aws serverless App

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-codestar

I have a Nodejs express app using Mongodb, and I want to go serverless.

Do I have to write again all my endpoints express  with aws Lambda ?
How can I convert my mongoose schemas to work with Dynamodb ?

I tried to use aws codestar service and found that I can use Express.js but just as a web service. I still don't understand why I can't use it with a web application.

I Need some clarification, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express ?

Answer (score 2):

if you need to convert your express.js app to serverless. You can use [serverless framework](https://serverless.com) and `serverless-http` module.

add serverless-http moduele to app

```
npm install --save express serverless-http
```

Then modify your app this way

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

module.exports.handler = serverless(app)
```

More details read [this](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/) article .

You can't use mongoose for dynamodb. try to use [dynamoose](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose)